# MAAS DHCP Server Setup, PXE TO1 TFTP File Not Found

Tags: networking, server, maas, dhcp, pxe

I am setting Ubuntu 14.04 MAAS Cluoud. I have setup the region and cluster controller.
For some reason, MAAS was not running DHCP even though (1) maas-dhcp and maas-dns were installed, and (2) Added a new interface (eth0) with managed DHCP and DNS.

So, I was forced to use ISC DHCP Server with manual configuration for eth0

DHCP Server seems to be running. Correct outputs are being printed out for "ip route".
When I do, "ps –ef | grep –I dhcp", it says its running.

For some reason, when I do sudo maas-probe-dhcp eth0, I get "No DHCP servers detected"

When I put in Ubuntu Server Installation CD on new node to be added, 
Network configuration succeeded I can see its talking to DHCP Server. Getting IP address..I even tried Ubuntu desktop CD...Not connected to internet. ping google.com fails.

Problem A: Is my DHCP server running successfully? What's causing the above issues? How can I fix the same?

Problem B: On new node to be added, PXE boot fails. Error messages are..
PXE-TO1: File not found
PXE-E3B: TFTP Error - File Not found
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks